# Android AutoCompleteTextView For Mentioning People

Tags: java, android, autocomplete

currently I am working with android to develop a social media apps. In this application, I would like to allow the user to mention each other (like in twitter, fb, instagram, etc). I have tried to use AutoCompleteTextView. However, it only show suggestion for the first words, not for the next one.

For example, in current system:
If I type: "@ab" for the first word, then it will show the list of suggestions. But, when I type: "hi, @ab", then it will not show any suggestions.

Anyone know how to fix this and provides some example? Here is how I create the AutoCompleteTextVIew in my apps:

```
AutoCompleteTextView et_comment = new AutoCompleteTextView(context);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, user_follow);
et_comment.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` instead of AutoCompleteTextView and set `setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());`

Answer (score 0):

You need to override getFilter() method.

```
    adapterSearchProducts = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listProductName) {
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i(TAG, "getFilter()");
            return myFilter;
        }
    };
```

Giving you the concept filter class, do some magic with in it with strings.

```
    /*
     * Custom filter
     */
    Filter myFilter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            Log.i(TAG, "constraint = " + constraint);

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();


            /**
            * Do your work here. Play with constraint.
            * Make tmp array list and work with it
            */

            // following two lines is very important
            // as publish result can only take FilterResults objects
            synchronized (this) {
            filterResults.values = "array-list";
            filterResults.count = "array-list-size";
            Log.i(TAG, "filterResults.count ==  " + filterResults.count);
            }

            return filterResults;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence contraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "results.count > 0 :: " + results.count);

                listProductName.clear(); // clear your original array list

                listProductName.addAll((List<String>) results.values);
                // add all tmp result to original result

                adapterSearchProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // notify your data set change
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "results.count <= 0  :: " + results.count);
                adapterSearchProducts.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
```